# Can a draggable div be true or receive a value when held over another div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, draggable, droppable

I have a div, a key, which I want to unlock a door with, another div. Can this draggable div receive a value, e.g. 1 or true when hovered over the locked door?

In this example code there is a problem. When `goldenKey` gets `mousedown` it turns `true`. That means the `if` statement is fulfilled and whatever div that is dropped into the locked door, e.g. another key-div, will prompt the `alert`, the `fadeOut`, and the color change to occur.

So is there a way for the `goldenKey` to receive a value, or true/false, when it is hovered over the locked door div? Or is there another easier way to solve this that I am missing?

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="item" id="goldenKey"></div>
   <div id="door" class="lockedDoor"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    position:relative;
    width:667px;
    height:375px;
    background-color:#999;
}
.item{
    position:absolute;
}
#goldenKey{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:10;
    background-color:gold;
    left:230px;
    top:100px;
}
#door{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:70px;
    height:110px;
    background-color:tomato;
}
.lockedDoor{
    position:relative;
    width:70px;
    height:110px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.item').draggable({
    accept: ".item",
    containment: '#container', 
    cursor: 'pointer',
    revert: function(is_valid_drop){
            console.log("is_valid_drop = " + is_valid_drop);
            if(!is_valid_drop){
               console.log("revert triggered");
               return true;
            } else {
                //Other
            }
        }
    });

var goldenKey = false;

$('#goldenKey').mousedown(function(){
    goldenKey = true;
});
    $('.lockedDoor').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(goldenKey){
                alert ('Door opened');
                $('#goldenKey').fadeOut(500);
                $('#door').css('background-color', 'blue');
            }else{
                alert ('Door locked');
            }

            var $this = $(this);
            $this.append(ui.draggable);

            var width = $this.width();
            var height = $this.height();
            var cntrLeft = width / 2 - ui.draggable.width() / 2;
            var cntrTop = height / 2 - ui.draggable.height() / 2;

            ui.draggable.css({
                left: cntrLeft + "px",
                top: cntrTop + "px"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an event [over( event, ui )](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over) especially for that in droppable jQuery UI.

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
  over: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

You should read the API carefully before posting an issue.

Comment: So in this example it would go something about this?      `$('.lockedDoor').droppable({
  over: function( event, ui ){
    goldenKey = true;
   }
 });`

Comment: Yes, you can add any logic there which handles key.  `.droppable({ over: function( event, ui ){ var key = getKeyById(); key.isTheRightKey(); } });` whatever is your logic

Comment: @YamadaAkira just add it in your `.droppable` definition you already have

Comment: I have this now `$('.lockedDoor').droppable({
  over: function( event, ui ) {
   goldenKey = true;
   console.log('This is true');}` But the problem is that anything that goes over the droppbale now makes it true.

Comment: Try setting something similar to the 'receiving' `div` and check the two global variables to ensure a match. For example: `draggingKey = true` in one `over` event and `draggingDoor = true` on the other, if both are true, the key is on the (right) door